# Need to clear cache and reindex product by ids

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, cache, reindex

I have an array with 500 products ids, I need to reindex these products and cache clean them. I don't want to reindex all because I have more than 100 000 products in DB, same for cache.

Do you know what is the best practice to do it quickly ?

I'm in Magento 2.1.10.

Thank you ! :)

Comment: Its possible via command. run commands:

Cache Clean
php bin/magento cache:clean

Cache Flush
php bin/magento cache:flush


Reindexing
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for your answer but maybe i was unclear.
If I have an array with ids, it means that I need to do it programatically. I checked the event manager dispatch for cache et the indexerFactory for the index but I'm not sure if it's the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a function to index product :

```
public function reindexByProductsIds($productIds, $indexLists)
{
    foreach($indexLists as $indexList) {
        $categoryIndexer = $this->indexerRegistry->get($indexList);
        if (!$categoryIndexer->isScheduled()) {
            $categoryIndexer->reindexList(array_unique($productIds));
        }
    }
}
```

where $indexLists is an array like `['catalog_product_attribute']`

And for cache I used : `$this->cacheManager->clean($idsToCacheClean);` where `$this->cacheManager` is `Magento\Framework\App\CacheInterface`